# How to update item from listview in main form to textbox in second form in windows form application in c#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms-designer

I create a program for an accountant. I have buttons for add product, delete product, add quantity of products, sell product and profit(count profit from all products in list) and listview for products with columns product, quantity, 
purchase price and profit. I have problem with button "add quantity of products" my idea is, when I select product in listview and than click on the button "add quantity of products" I want to open a new window (new form) and to pass all the values from selected item from listview to second form, make mathematical calculations with that values and then pass that new values to selected item in first form ie to update select item in list view. How can I resolve that?
This is my code:

**Form1:**

```
public int Index;

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form3 form3 = new Form3();
        form3.Show();
        form3.Hide();

        if (listView1.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
        {
            this.listView1.Items[0].Focused = true;
            this.listView1.Items[0].Selected = true;
            this.Index = listView1.FocusedItem.Index;
            ListViewItem selectedItem = listView1.SelectedItems[0];

            form3.GetData(listView1.Items[listView1.FocusedItem.Index].SubItems[0].Text, listView1.Items[listView1.FocusedItem.Index].SubItems[1].Text,
                          listView1.Items[listView1.FocusedItem.Index].SubItems[2].Text, listView1.Items[listView1.FocusedItem.Index].SubItems[3].Text);
            DialogResult ans = form3.ShowDialog();
            if (ans == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                listView1.FocusedItem.SubItems[0].Text = form3.Prozz;
                listView1.FocusedItem.SubItems[1].Text = form3.Kolii;
                listView1.FocusedItem.SubItems[2].Text = form3.Cenaa;
                listView1.FocusedItem.SubItems[3].Text = form3.Proff;
            }
        }
    }
```

**Form2:**

```
  public string Prozz { get; set; }
    public string Kolii { get; set; }
    public string Cenaa { get; set; }
    public string Proff { get; set; }

    public Form3()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public void GetData(string Proi, string Kol, string Cena, string Profit)
    {
        textBox1.Text = Kol;
        textBox2.Text = Cena;
        textBox3.Text = Profit;
        textBox6.Text = Proi;
    }
    public void SetData(string Proz, string Kol, string NabCena, string Prof)
    {
        int x = int.Parse(Kol);
        double y = double.Parse(NabCena);
        double z = double.Parse(Prof);
        int a = int.Parse(textBox4.Text);
        double b = double.Parse(textBox5.Text);

        int Kolicina = x + a;
        double sumNabavnaCena = (x * y + a * b) / (x + a);
        double Profit = z - Kolicina * sumNabavnaCena;

        Prozz = Convert.ToString(Proz);
        Kolii = Convert.ToString(Kolicina);
        Cenaa = Convert.ToString(sumNabavnaCena);
        Proff = Convert.ToString(Profit);
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SetData(textBox6.Text, textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text, textBox3.Text);
        this.button1.Text = "OK";
        this.button1.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;

        this.Close();
    }
```

Comment: I know that my code is not good, I need proposal for new, cleaner and simply better code who works! :)

Comment: One more thing, in second form I only have two textbox for quantity and purchase price, and two buttons for submit and back. I want when I press submit to update item in listview in main form with new values.

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to do this when you're only talking about a couple of textboxes is to create a couple of properties on Form2 to hold the values from your listview.

```
public string firstValue {get; set;}
public string secondValue {get; set;}
```

In your form_load event

```
//this will display the values from the listview
textBox1.Text = firstValue;
textBox2.Text = secondValue;
```

in the buttonClick event that you have set to dialogresult.OK

```
//this puts the changes back into the property
firstValue = textBox1.Text;
secondValue = textBox2.Text;
```

Now the key to all of this is that you need to fill this information in Form1

```
var f2 as new Form2();
//fill the firstValue propery with the 3rd column of the listview 
f2.firstValue = listview1.FocusedItem.SubItems[2].Text;
//fill the secondValue property with the 4th column of the listview
f2.secondValue = listview1.FocusedItem.SubItems[3].Text;
//show f2 as a dialog
DialogResult ans = f2.ShowDialog();
if(ans == DialogResult.OK)
{
    //update the listview with the values from the properties of form2
    listview1.focusedItem.SubItems[2].Text = f2.firstValue;
    listview1.FocusedItem.SubItems[3].Text = f2.secondValue;
}
```

Code Removed - It is covered in new code:
Image Removed
**Here's the code I used**
FORM1

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Form3 form3 = null;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
/*  private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
//You won't need this. It just populates my 
//listview with some Dummy Data. I'll leave
//it here in case you want to mess with it
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            var lv = new ListViewItem();
            lv.Text = "Item" + i;
            lv.SubItems.Add((6+ i).ToString());
            lv.SubItems.Add((i + 7).ToString());
            lv.SubItems.Add((i + 3).ToString());
            listView1.Items.Add(lv);
        }
    }*/
    //public int Index; //not needed
    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        form3 = new Form3();
        if (listView1.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
        {
            //this.listView1.Items[0].Focused = true;
            //this.listView1.Items[0].Selected = true;
            //this.Index = listView1.FocusedItem.Index;
            //ListViewItem selecteditem = listView1.SelectedItems[0];

            form3.GetData(listView1.FocusedItem.Text, listView1.FocusedItem.SubItems[1].Text,
                            listView1.FocusedItem.SubItems[2].Text, listView1.FocusedItem.SubItems[3].Text);
            DialogResult ans = form3.ShowDialog();
            if (ans == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                listView1.FocusedItem.Text = form3.Prozz;
                listView1.FocusedItem.SubItems[1].Text = form3.Kolii;
                listView1.FocusedItem.SubItems[2].Text = form3.Cenaa;
                listView1.FocusedItem.SubItems[3].Text = form3.Proff;
            }
        }
        form3 = null;
    }
}
```

FORM3:

```
public partial class Form3 : Form
{
    public string Prozz { get; set; }
    public string Kolii { get; set; }
    public string Cenaa { get; set; }
    public string Proff { get; set; }

    public Form3()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void GetData(string Proi, string Kol, string Cena, string Profit)
    {
        textBox1.Text = Kol;
        textBox2.Text = Cena;
        textBox3.Text = Profit;
        textBox6.Text = Proi;
    }

    public void SetData(string Proz, string Kol, string NabCena, string Prof)
    {
        int x = int.Parse(Kol);
        double y = double.Parse(NabCena);
        double z = double.Parse(Prof);
        int a = int.Parse(textBox4.Text);
        double b = double.Parse(textBox5.Text);

        int Kolicna = x + a;
        double subNabavnaCena = (x * y + a * b) / (x + a);
        double Profit = z - Kolicna * subNabavnaCena;

        Prozz = Proz.ToString();
        Kolii = Kolicna.ToString();
        Cenaa = subNabavnaCena.ToString();
        Proff = Profit.ToString();
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SetData(textBox6.Text, textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text, textBox3.Text);

        //you should move these two lines up under InitializeComponent()
        //otherwise you will never see the button text set to OK and you
        //can set the dialogResult before you need the button.
        this.button1.Text = "OK";
        this.button1.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
    }

}
```

Comment: ty for your answer but I try to use your code but it doesnt work or I doing something wrong? This is how it looks my new code http://gallery.uroszlatkovic.com/#!home
Any sugestion?

Comment: If you see I dont having problem to reading values from listview, I have problem to write new values back to listview.

Comment: @Uros Zlatkovic, can you edit your question with your newly updated code? It makes it hard to read when looking at images. Also, how many total forms are you involving in this? Please include the form classes so that we can tell which form has what code more easily. I get the feeling there are 3 forms involved but that may just be mislabeled information.

Comment: I make the changes. I have one main form and three more forms for add product, add quantity of product( this code is for this form and button for that control) and sell product, so I have four forms.

Comment: @Uros Zlatkovic, see the EDIT section of my answer. I posted a change to some of your code which seems to work on my end.

Comment: ty for you effort but it's not working, I dont know why! I posted you everything I done. Can it be that the code will work with tag property or I must use index of item from list or something else?

Comment: See image at the bottom of my answer that I got using your code and remarking out those lines.

Comment: yea the code is working I checked the math. I dont know then what is the problem with my code and why it's not working. 
Ty once again in any case!

Comment: Thought I'd post the actual code I used so you can compare against yours. It's basically the same as yours with the exception of using `FocusedItem` instead of `Items[<index>]`

Comment: and where you use method SetData(); from form3? I use it in the control buton in form3 and what else you put in the button control? By the way sometimes VS 2015 dont work properly so I try it in VS 2010 and it's also dont working.

Comment: Sorry about that, yes, it's in a button on form3. Somehow I missed copying over that code. Fixed Now.  By the way, this is basically your code. I just posted it back so you could compare to your system.

Comment: The problem is solved. Code   this.Close();   in the button control in form3 is making all the trouble. I removed it and the program is now working. Ty once again for your advice's and for your time!